# Meaning of 'have it they did'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, inversion

> When they had the ultimate audacity and have it they did then you needn't wonder that everything was turned upside down.

In this sentence, what is the meaning of 'have it they did'? Please tell me I have no idea... It's too difficult:(

Comment: It means "... and they actually did have it to a great extent." The emphasis is given by reversing the usual word order and putting the subject ("they") before the verb ("have").

Comment: Hello LeeLeeLee . You've quoted a line of text.  You haven't told us who said it and cited the source.  You must do this.  Please edit to cite the source. If you can link to the source, that is even better.

Comment: *and have it they did* is an optional ***parenthetical*** element, which must be set off by dashes or commas (*pauses,* in speech). But the "non-standard" word order is just a stylised / rhetorical alternative to the "natural" English sequence: *and they did have it* (the ultimate audacity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It" is "the ultimate audacity".

So the sentence could be written

> When they had the ultimate audacity - and have the ultimate audacity they did - then...

Which could in turn be then placed in a more "normal" word order

> When they had the ultimate audacity, and they did have the ultimate audacity, then...

As user105719 observed, the change in the usual word order is to provide literary emphasis.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! helped me a lot